# Has there been a headless state?

Tags: political-system, head-of-state

Has there been a state without an office satisfying the definition of a head of state? This question is mostly about the modern times because I'm not sure if we can give a satisfactory definition for outdated political systems. Please feel free to comment on this, but still the main focus of this question is on the modern world.

Comment: Would Andorra count? It has two heads of state, together (the co-princes).

Comment: I'm sure I could google some headless heads of state. Would that count?

Comment: @myself forget that, in [December 1967](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_Holt#Disappearance), Australia not only lacked the head, but the entire body!

Comment: If I recall correctly, most members of the state lost their heads during the French Revolution!

Comment: @Andrew That was the Head of Government, though, not the Head of State!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Switzerland** lacks a single head of state, though the members of the 7-head government take it in turns to represent the country as such abroad during the 7-year government term. See also Wikipedia on [Politics of Switzerland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_Switzerland).

Answer (score 15):

While the U.S. was under the *Articles of Confederation*, the *President of The United States in Congress Assembled* was not a head of state. Instead, the role was to ensure impartiality of the congress and enforcement of rules. [Articles of Confederation, Presidents of the Congress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articles_of_Confederation#Presidents_of_the_Congress)

Answer (score 4):

In the USSR the head of state was collective: the Presidium of Supreme Council. The state was usually represented and laws signed by the Chairman of the Presidium, but he actually did not have any powers: if he would refuse to sign a law for instance, it would be signed by his deputy.

Answer (score 2):

Since 1974, The Socialist Federal Republic of Yugoslavia (SFRY) had a collective head of state, the [Presidency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidency_of_Yugoslavia).

It was usually represented by a chairman, a rotating position between the republics and SAPs.

Answer (score -1):

I think, Bosnia doesn't have a single head of state. There is a 3 member committee consisting of ethnic serb, ethnic croat, and ethnic Bosniac member each.

The committee has a chairman, and he becomes a chairman by rotation.